# How to get TRAINABLE VARIABLES whose names contain specific chars for retraining in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow we can use `tf.get_collection` to get variables with specific prefix. But how can we get variables whose names contain specific characters in order to do some tasks like retraining?

Toy Example code

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.variable_scope('net'):
    var_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 5],stddev=0.35),name='var1')
    with tf.variable_scope('retrain'):
        var_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 5], stddev=0.35),name='var2')
        var_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]), name="var3")
```

In this example, `print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,"net"))` will return all the trainable variables.

However, `print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,"retrain"))` will return a null list `[]` instead of `var_2` and `var_3`.

Assume that at real conditions, **the precise root variable scope `net` can be `net` ,`net_1`… Except printing all the trainable variables or using `tensorboard` to find the prefix of the variable names**(to figure out whether it's `net\retrain` or `net_1\retrain`), can we use some functions like `tf.get_collection` to get `var_2` and `var_3`?

Comment: Have I answered your question? (The other guy copied mine 20 min later for reasons I don't understand) --- By the way, please don't change your Q to something completely different , especially after answers were given - this won't win you a lot of friends on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually after your answering, I find out that I didn't explain my Q clearly. In the first sentence I expressed that I try to find function that use `containing` instead of `prefix`, but my example didn't fully express this idea. `Your answer solved my example`. Maybe using `prefix` is the only way in `TensorFlow` API, because it assumes that we can know exactly what the `prefix` scope is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scopes are nested. You want to use

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, "net/retrain")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the variables inside the scope `retrain`.

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='net/retrain').
```